# Get settings from a text file in Java

Tags: java, properties, resources, settings

I'm working over Eclipse, and I have created a res folder outside mi src folder. In it, I have created a text file called "config.cfg". Looks like this:

```
# System configuration
# Comments will automatically be excluded by the program

radiomodemPort=20001

sisnetPort=5562

sisnetHost=213.229.135.3

sisnetUser=jogg

sisnetPass=jogg
```

The code written to read it is not working: it doesn't load any of the variables stored. My code is:

```
private String sisnetHost;
private int sisnetPort;
private int radiomodemPort;
private String sisnetUser;
private String sisnetPass;

private boolean sisnetHostLoaded;
private boolean sisnetPortLoaded;
private boolean radiomodemPortLoaded;
private boolean sisnetUserLoaded;
private boolean sisnetPassLoaded;

public boolean getSettingsFromFile(){
        Properties config = new Properties();
        try {
            config.load(new FileInputStream("res/config.cfg"));
            Enumeration<Object> en = config.keys();
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) en.nextElement();
                if(key.equals(sisnetHost)){
                    sisnetHost = (String)config.get(key);
                    sisnetHostLoaded = true;
                }
                if(key.equals(sisnetPort)){
                    sisnetPort = (Integer)config.get(key);
                    sisnetPortLoaded = true;
                }
                if(key.equals(sisnetUser)){
                    sisnetUser = (String)config.get(key);
                    sisnetUserLoaded = true;
                }
                if(key.equals(sisnetPass)){
                    sisnetPass = (String)config.get(key);
                    sisnetPassLoaded = true;
                }
                if(key.equals(radiomodemPort)){
                    radiomodemPort = (Integer)config.get(key);
                    radiomodemPortLoaded = true;
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        if(!(sisnetHostLoaded && sisnetPortLoaded && sisnetUserLoaded && sisnetPassLoaded && radiomodemPortLoaded))
            fillUnloadedSettings();
        return true;
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try doing a `System.out.println(new File("res/config.cfg").getAbsolutePath());` and verify that you're definitely getting the right file. Also, why are you looping it rather than just doing `sisnetHost = config.get("<key>");`, etc.?

Comment: try to do this config.load(new FileInputStream("res/config.cfg")); System.out.println(config); what is the result?

Comment: First try to check if the file location you are providing is correct. you may try some print statement in the catch part to know if it is actually throwing some error.

Comment: @Thor84no Main problem was what Costi pointed: what a miss! Anyway thank you for your advice on how to improve the code without the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `equals` test, you're comparing each key with your instance variables (which seem to have default values: `null` for objects, `0` for numbers etc.). Use the actual strings to test the keys:

```
if(key.equals("sisnetHost")) // NOT if(key.equals(sisnetHost))
```

Usually it's recommended to to call `equals` on the literal / constant in order to eliminate the risk of a NPE:

```
if ("sisnetHost".equals(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ready static class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class Settings {
    public static String Get(String name,String defVal){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(reader);
            reader.close();
            return props.getProperty(name);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        }
    }
    public static Integer Get(String name,Integer defVal){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(reader);
            reader.close();
            return Integer.valueOf(props.getProperty(name));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        }
    }
    public static Boolean Get(String name,Boolean defVal){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(reader);
            reader.close();
            return Boolean.valueOf(props.getProperty(name));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
            return defVal;
        }
    }
    public static void Set(String name, String value){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            props.load(reader);
            props.setProperty(name, value.toString());
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configFile);
            props.store(writer, Variables.SETTINGS_COMMENT);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
    public static void Set(String name, Integer value){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            props.load(reader);
            props.setProperty(name, value.toString());
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configFile);
            props.store(writer,Variables.SETTINGS_COMMENT);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
    public static void Set(String name, Boolean value){
        File configFile = new File(Variables.SETTINGS_FILE);
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
            props.load(reader);
            props.setProperty(name, value.toString());
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(configFile);
            props.store(writer,Variables.SETTINGS_COMMENT);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // file does not exist
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // I/O error
            logger.error(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here sample:

```
    Settings.Set("valueName1","value");
    String val1=Settings.Get("valueName1","value");
    Settings.Set("valueName2",true);
    Boolean val2=Settings.Get("valueName2",true);
    Settings.Set("valueName3",100);
    Integer val3=Settings.Get("valueName3",100);
```